# How to split a text using a string delimiter with R's strsplit?

Tags: r, string, strsplit

Let's say I have a text file of a book that contains multiple chapters that contain text.

```
x <- "Chapter 1 Text. Text. Chapter 2 Text. Text. Chapter 3 Text. Text."
```

I would like to split up this text and get a separate file for each chapter.

```
"Chapter 1 Text. Text." "Chapter 2 Text. Text." "Chapter 3 Text. Text."
```

Ideally, I would like to save each file according to the chapter, so Chapter 1, Chapter 2 and Chapter 3.

I have tried the following:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "Chapter", perl = TRUE))
```

Unfortunately, this deletes the delimiter, which I would like to keep.

I have also tried the following:

```
unlist(strsplit(x, "(?<=Chapter)", perl=TRUE))
```

Unfortunately, this only seems to work for a single character but not for a string.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use regex lookahead

```
strsplit(x, "\\s(?=Chapter)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "Chapter 1 Text. Text." "Chapter 2 Text. Text." "Chapter 3 Text. Text."
```

Comment: Hey arun, could you please tell me what is the significance of using `[[1]]` here? As I could see without that also output is same, will be grateful to you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  `x` is a vector of length 1. when we split it, it becomes a `list` of of length 1 with split elements as a vector.  By doing the `[[1]]`, we are extracting the element (vector) within the list of length 1.  You can check the ouptut of `strsplit(x, "\\s(?=Chapter)", perl = TRUE)`.  It becomes more clear